# How to delete a built-in indicator ( NOT an iCustom() one ) entirely from MT4 platform?

Tags: metatrader4, mt4

I wonder how do I permanently delete indicator from MT4 software?

Indicator, in my case Average True Range, is the original one and NOT a custom.

I would like to delete it from menu, so entirely from the MetaTrader Terminal 4 software and not only from a chart. This indicator is a total disaster, by far worst indicator ever seen - impossible to trade according to it, impossible to follow it, wrong data, no signals where to enter Short/Long online, no resources about this indicator, nothing.

I would like to get rid of it, but how do I delete it?

It is not a Custom Indicator, so I need help getting rid of it.

Answer (score 1):

### Bad news: there is no way to achieve this.

Built-in indicators are simply hardwired into the MetaTrader Terminal ( MT4 )

---

### Good news: there is no must to launch it.

So, given no activation has taken place, all your wishes are met.

---